# Audio Faster in Windows Live Movie Maker

Tags: video, windows-movie-maker

When I import videos from my Flip Mino HD, the audio speeds up on the clips so everything is just squeaky.  If I import video from other sources it is fine.

Is there anyway to fix this or change the audio speed in Windows Live Movie Maker?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with how the Flip Mono HD currently records video. [Other users](http://www.pcmech.com/article/review-flip-mino-hd/comment-page-1/#comment-19872) are experiencing it as well.

A solution as pointed out by other users, is to convert the video before dropping it into an editing program. [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) can help you do this. x264 Would be recommended for no quality loss between the conversion, then after editing you can use a lossy codec is you prefer.

Comment: Handbrake crashes when I try to convert video from the flip.

Comment: Thats odd as it uses ffmpeg as the backend. I'm guessing something is really weird about their recording format. You can try using a few other video converters before ruling the recording format as the problem: http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/

Answer (score 0):

Having Intervideo's WinDVD on the same computer can cause this.

It is written up in the  [Windows Movie Maker 2.1 FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/moviemaker/21/faq.mspx). Maybe it is somehow related to your issue?

> Q: Why is the audio distorted, and
>   playing much faster than normal?
>
> A: This can occur if the InterVideo
>   Audio Decoder (Iviaudio.ax) video
>   filter, which is installed with
>   InterVideo WinDVD, is on your
>   computer. To fix the issue, make sure
>   this video filter is turned off in
>   Windows Movie Maker:
>
> 1. In Windows Movie Maker, on the Tools menu, click Options, and then
>      click the Compatibility tab.
> 2. To turn off a filter, clear its check box.

Comment: I'm using Windows Live Movie Maker, not the older Windows Movie Maker.  I also don't have WinDVD installed.

Answer (score 0):

Deinstall the Flip software and reboot, that works too. Windows Movie Maker Live (latest edition) has more features than Flip, for me it works much better.

Comment: I am revieing late answers and I am unsure if I should upvote it for giving an alternative method to solve the problem or if I should downvote it for bashing another software. So I guess I will just lleave that comment and welcome your contribution.